# How to debug DAX formulas in an SSAS Tabular model?

Tags: visual-studio, powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

Is there any wa to get the debug of the created DAX final formulas in a tabular model?

Comment: Dax Studio is handy for this: https://daxstudio.org/

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Profiler is the most recommended tool for debugging DAX queries. For more information, please refer to the links below :

http://mdxdax.blogspot.com/2011/12/dax-query-plan-part-1-introduction.html

http://www.sqlbi.com/wp-content/uploads/DAX-Query-Plans.pdf